# How to dynamically extract date from different time stamp format?

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime, python-dateutil, python-iso8601

I have following time stamp received as event to the lambda function where i need to extract the date from the timestamp

```
import datetime as dt

case1_time=2021-06-23T00:05:05-04:00
case2_time=2021-08-03T04:57:52.30-04:00

def get_date_from_ts(timestamp):
    extracted_date=dt.datetime.fromisoformat(timestamp)

#case 1
print(get_date_from_ts(case1_time))
## This will extract the date as = 2021-06-23

#case2
print(get_date_from_ts(case2_time))

ValueError: Invalid isoformat string
```

i need to handle both case by the way..
can anyone help how to resolve this format issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can take this as example:

Input:

```
from datetime import datetime

today_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

print(today_date)
```

Output:

```
19/08/2021
```

Try to transform "case1_time=2021-06-23T00:05:05-04:00" before it is saved in a variable.

Comment: Hi @Dave may be i am not getting with example. how i can refer the given timestamp instead of current datetime?

Comment: where does this timespamp come from? Is it an output or do you hardcode or copy every timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

How about simply extracting the date part from the timestamp?

```py
def get_date_from_ts(timestamp):
    extracted_date=dt.datetime.fromisoformat(timestamp[:10])
    return extracted_date
```

```
Output
2021-06-23 00:00:00
2021-08-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: HI @norie, this not giving exact date . you mean python string manipulation to extract date?

Answer (score 0):

Got a simplest way by spliting at certain point

```
#Convert to string
string_date_time=str(case1_time)

#split at specific location - T00:05:05-04:00
string_date_time.split('T')[0]
#output:
2021-06-23
```